# jQuery UI Multiple Select not working in .aspx page that is content for a master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, master-pages

I'm trying to use this jquery plugin (http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) on an aspx page with many different gridviews. The page code is within an asp:content tag. I'm placing my select options in an asp:view outside of an asp:gridview. The page uses a master page. I have the multiselect widget working in a blank page, but I can't get it to work with my master page. I've tried adding my css/script links/document.ready() in the gridview I'm using it with. I've tried adding it to the head tag of the master page using an asp:contentplaceholder on the master and a separate asp:content tag in my aspx page. I can't for the life of me get the multiselect to take on the UI of the widget.

I've noticed on the blank page with the working widget, the jquery adds a button and a couple spans with the classes needed to style the multiselect. In my aspx page, these items do not get added.

```
<button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 240.60000002384186px;">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>5 selected</span></button>


//My Code
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/jquery.multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#example").multiselect({
            minWidth: 235
        });
        $("#example").multiselect("checkAll");
    });
</script>

<select id="example" name="example" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

I've tried removing all other css/script references in the master page and that didn't work. Is there something else that might be conflicting?

Comment: is `example` select has `runat="server"` specified?

Comment: No. If I do specify that it won't allow me to set the multiple attribute to multiple.

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanels? Show master and content pages source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading my scripts in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

You are falling victom of [`Control.ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx), which is `inherit`:

**Option 1:**

Change your script to use the dynamically created ClientID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sel = #<%= example.ClientID %>";
        $(sel).multiselect({
            minWidth: 235
        });
        $(sel).multiselect("checkAll");
    });
</script>
```

**Option 2:**

Leave you script as is and change the ClientIDMode to Static:

```
<select id="example" name="example" multiple="multiple" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The ClientIDMode doesn't work, I'm assuming since select isn't an asp control. I'm not real familiar with that clientId request. It's telling me example is not declared, and is the quotation mark extra or did you forget the leading quote?

Comment: When I inspect the example select element it still has id='example'.