# select2 not working in aspx page with masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I've got a webforms application that is built with masterpages. Just recently I've been trying to get a select2 drop-down onto one of the forms.

When I run the code in a stand alone page, it's fine. But when inheriting from the masterpage, it doesn't work very well - see images for examples.

When i Press F12 in Chrome, there are no jQuery errors.

In the Head of the masterpage I have the following, in this order:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

And in the Content1 of the child page, I have the Select2 js links:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, at the very bottom of the form (in the child page) I have this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#selectContacts").select2({ placeholder: 'Select Member' });
        });
    </script>
```

I've tried moving the select2 scripts out of the child page, and into the header of the masterpage too, but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: no masterpage - works as expected]
[image: with materpage - no selecting the same way]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol ... after searching for a few hours... i post the question then stumble on the answer 10 minutes later!

[jQuery UI Multiple Select not working in .aspx page that is content for a master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407362/jquery-ui-multiple-select-not-working-in-aspx-page-that-is-content-for-a-master)

All I needed to do was add this option to the select:

```
clientidmode="Static"
```

Comment: Or use:  $("#<%=selectContacts.ClientID %>").select2({ ...

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
   <option value="example1">example1</option>
    <option value="example2">example2</option>
    <option value="example3">example3</option>
    <option value="example4">example4</option>
    <option value="example5">example5</option>
    <option value="example6">example6</option>
</select>
```